# Get Text not Value of Dropdown (Select) input with React

Tags: javascript, html, validation, dom, reactjs

Using react I can grab the value of the selected element via `target.value`

however in my current case I want both the value as its an ID of sorts and the face value of the option. How do I grab that with react? Is that plausible?

By face value I mean the Words in between `<option value='123'> TEXT </option>`

I want to be able to get the "TEXT"

Answer (score 2):

I would just give this select box an id and grab this value using normal JavaScript function attached to your click handler or whatever function you want to execute within your React component.

**// regular javascript way**

```
var yourElement = document.getElementById(elementId);

    if (yourElement.selectedIndex == -1)
        return null;

    return yourElement.options[yourElement.selectedIndex].text;
```

Answer (score 1):

`event.target` gives you the HTMLSelectElement, from there you have access to a few other things such as `HTMLSelectElement.selectedOptions`.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement):

> HTMLSelectElement.selectedOptions (Read only)
>
> Returns a live HTMLCollection containing the set of options that are selected.

So from there you can get the `HTMLOptionElement` and the `text`

Put it all together and you'll have something like this:

```
var selectedOption = e.target.selectedOptions[0];
console.log(selectedOption.value); // 123
console.log(selectedOption.text); // TEXT
```